# How to order a XML return depending on its tags values?

Tags: php, xml

Let's say I have a php page that dynamically loads the return of a method that returns a XML.
The XML is something like this:

```
<SYSTEM>
  <GUY>
    <ID>500</ID>
    <NAME>Joseph</NAME>
    <EMAIL>joseph@mark</EMAIL>
    <ERROR />
  </GUY>
  <GUY>
    <ID>510</ID>
    <NAME>Richard</NAME>
    <EMAIL>richard@gmail.com</EMAIL>
  </GUY>
</SYSTEM>
```

Now my PHP file has a simple "if" that checks for the ERROR tag. If it's detected, then it prints an error.
The result right now is the error being printed BEFORE the correct print (Richard). Both should be printed, but I want to put the errors on the bottom, after the correct results. The error is printed first because it's the first result of the XML. How can I bypass that?
I think it may be simple, but I'm really not getting it.

My PHP verification is something like this (it runs based on the number of GUY tags, so it'll be twice according to my XML above):

```
$xmlresult = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$error = $xmlresult->xpath("//ERROR");

if($error==true){
   echo "error message here";
} else {
   echo "wee! no errors!"
}
```

Comment: What code are you using?

Comment: Added the PHP verification to the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would approach this would be to temporarily store any error results in a list as I walked through the XML file, and print out the good ones as you go. Then, once you reach the end of the file, you can walk through your list of errors and print them after all of the good ones.

This sort of simple algorithm should work for pretty much any method of going through the XML, both with a parsing library that gives back nice objects, as well as more brute-force string-based methods.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this sorted my problem out. :-)